# How to Join the table to get the records like left join

Tags: sql, oracle

I have Table1 with below records.

```
H_ID   STATUS
1001   Approved
1002   Approved
1003   Approved
```

The second Table has below records

```
H_ID   L_NO    ITEM_ID   LOCATION   QTY
1001    1      220050    S1         5
1002    1      220050    S2         1
1002    2      230050    S2         4
1003    1      220050    S3         3
1003    2      230050    S3         2
1003    3      240050    S3         5
```

Need your help to write sql query to get the below output

```
ITEM_ID       LOCATION  QTY
220050         S1        5
220050         S2        1
220050         S3        3
230050         S1        0
230050         S2        4
230050         S3        2
240050         S1        0
240050         S2        0
240050         S3        5
```

I'm new at SQL so need your help to build a query to get the output.
Thanks in anticipation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One option (quite simple) is to cross join distinct locations and items, and then outer join that combination to the 2nd table.

Sample data:

```
SQL> with
  2  t1 (h_id) as
  3    (select 1001 from dual union all
  4     select 1002 from dual union all
  5     select 1003 from dual
  6    ),
  7  t2 (h_id, item_id, location, qty) as
  8    (select 1001, 220050, 'S1', 5 from dual union all
  9     select 1002, 220050, 'S2', 1 from dual union all
 10     select 1002, 230050, 'S2', 4 from dual union all
 11     select 1003, 220050, 'S3', 3 from dual union all
 12     select 1003, 230050, 'S3', 2 from dual union all
 13     select 1003, 240050, 'S3', 5 from dual
 14    ),
```

Query begins here:

```
 15  locations as
 16    (select distinct location from t2),
 17  items as
 18    (select distinct item_id from t2)
 19  select i.item_id, l.location, nvl(b.qty, 0) qty
 20  from locations l cross join items i
 21       left join t2 b on b.location = l.location
 22                      and b.item_id = i.item_id
 23  order by i.item_id, l.location;

   ITEM_ID LOCATION          QTY
---------- ---------- ----------
    220050 S1                  5
    220050 S2                  1
    220050 S3                  3
    230050 S1                  0
    230050 S2                  4
    230050 S3                  2
    240050 S1                  0
    240050 S2                  0
    240050 S3                  5

9 rows selected.

SQL>
```

Comment: Getting Error for Line number 2 as "ORA-32033: Unsupported column aliasing."

Comment: It seems that you're running Oracle 10g (or even lower?). Because, line #2 really would raise that error. However, I think I said that query you need begins at line **#15** (just put WITH keyword in front of LOCATIONS), and that piece of code won't raise that error. BTW, it means that you can't use e.g. `WITH T1 (H_ID) AS (SELECT ...` but `WITH T1 AS (SELECT 1001 H_ID ...`

Comment: Thanks this exact i am looking for.
WITH LOCATIONS AS
 (SELECT DISTINCT LOCATION FROM APPS.TAB_LINES),
ITEMS AS
 (SELECT DISTINCT ITEM_ID FROM APPS.TAB_LINES)
SELECT I.ITEM_ID, L.LOCATION, SUM(NVL(B.QTY, 0)) QTY
  FROM LOCATIONS L
 CROSS JOIN ITEMS I
  LEFT JOIN APPS.TAB_LINES B
    ON B.LOCATION = L.LOCATION
   AND B.ITEM_ID = I.ITEM_ID
GROUP BY I.ITEM_ID, L.LOCATION
 ORDER BY I.ITEM_ID, L.LOCATION;